# How to pass a value in jquery function without using textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://www.codingsnow.com/2021/01/create-php-send-email-contact-form.html
In this code, how do i send  subject as "hi", what do I need to change in the function, I tried setting it as a string but it didn't work, also tried sending it directly in the data:{} ..it didnt work..

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var name = $("#name");
  var email = $("#email");
  var subject = $("#subject");
  var body = $("#body");

  if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject) && isNotEmpty(body)) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'sendEmail.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        name: name.val(),
        email: email.val(),
        subject: subject.val(),
        body: body.val()
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
        $('.sent-notification').text("Message Sent Successfully.");
      }
    });
  }
}

function isNotEmpty(caller) {
  if (caller.val() == "") {
    caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
    return false;
  } else
    caller.css('border', '');

  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 class="sent-notification"></h4>

<form id="myForm">
  <h2>Send an Email</h2>

  <label>Name</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
  <br><br>

  <label>Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email">
  <br><br>

  <label>Subject</label>
  <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder=" Enter Subject">
  <br><br>
  <-----------------------------------------------------will disable this..and then need to send subject as "hi" instead, from function <p>Message</p>
    <textarea id="body" rows="5" placeholder="Type Message"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send An Email">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Like... `var subject = "hi";`? I think i don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to send "hi" for the subject instead of the value the user typed in the `<input id="subject"` you just can hardcode it directly in the ajax method where you define the data:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: {
    name: name.val(),
    email: email.val(),
    subject: 'hi',
    body: body.val()
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: $message = "Submitted form by-" . "<br>" . "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>" . " Contact: " . $_POST['subject'] . "<br>" . "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "<br>" . " Project Description: " . $_POST['body'];
    $mail->Body = $body12;
this also worked